# Is there a way to edit my openshift configmap using oc command

Tags: python, automation, openshift, configmap

I am trying to create a simple automation to replace my config map content in OpenShift from the current one to an edited yaml file, I have tried many oc commands and failed, I was wondering if any one had an idea of how to do this.

Just to make u understand:
I'm using`oc get congifmap <configmap name>` to get the current configmap from my project,
Then I am using python to make my changes to the configmap data.
then I want to change the current config map to the new edited one.
I tried edit, apply, change but they all failed.

Would appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to work with "inputs" and "outputs".

Imagine a `lighttpd.conf`:

```js
server.modules = (
    "mod_scgi",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_accesslog"
)
```

```sh
oc create cm lighttpd --from-file lighttpd.conf
```

So, as a example, let's change the **mod_scgi** to **mod_fastcgi**. So I wrote this script:

```py
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
  if 'mod_scgi' in line:
    print(line.replace('scgi', 'fastcgi').rstrip())
  else:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

So, to change the `configMap`, update it's value and apply again:

```sh
oc get cm -o yaml | python modify.py | oc apply -f -
```

- `get -o yaml` prints all information on screen
- output goes to the script `modify.py`
- `modify.py` change and print the lines as they are read from standard input
- output goes to `oc`
- `oc apply -f -` reads from standard input and apply

Answer (score 1):

There is an`"oc"`command for such use case:`oc patch`

With`"oc patch"`you can edit, replace, add, remove parts of any OCP object

If you google "oc patch" you'll find many example on the net

[Official OCP v4.7 oc patch doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/cli_reference/openshift_cli/developer-cli-commands.html#patch)
[Tons of examples here](https://labs.consol.de/development/2019/04/08/oc-patch-unleashed.html)
[OC patch "man" page](https://www.mankier.com/1/oc-patch)
[Other examples](https://gist.github.com/rafaeltuelho/111850b0db31106a4d12a186e1fbc53e)